# in PHP, Alter the value of a variable from an included file before the value is computed

Tags: php, html

I currently have a header.php page which stores all the styles and positions of my header and layout. I then have a contactus.php page which includes the header.php page.

```
-----CONTACTUS.PHP:
<?php 
    include 'header.php' 
    $classnamehere='"linkStyleTwo"'     //Here is where I want to update the value
?>
```

The main links at the top of my page are styled in a certain way using:

```
------HEADER.PHP:
<?php 
    $classnamehere= '"linkStyleOne"' ?>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class= <?php echo $classnamehere ; ?>......
```

I want to alter the style of the link that the person has clicked, so that it pops out indicating to the person which page they are on. Currently, when I try altering the value of $classnamehere inside of contactus.php (by simply assigning it a new value) to change the class printed inside the `<a href>` tag, nothing happens. It executes the include command, and outputs the value that was stated inside header.php, ignoring my attempts to change the value on the new page.

Is there any way to change the value within contactus.php only, while still keeping the initial value inside header.php so that all the other pages can still use the 'default' style?

Edit: Inside contactus.php, can I change the value of a variable obtained (included) from header.php without actually 'changing' the global variable?

Comment: Where abouts are you overriding the `$classnamehere` variable?

Comment: I am trying to overwrite from within contactus.php.

Comment: I would just load header.php using file_get_contents(), do a search and replace for "linkStyleOne", then eval() the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
   -----CONTACTUS.PHP:
    <?php 
        include 'header.php' 
        $classnamehere='"linkStyleTwo"'     //Here is where I want to update the value
    ?>

The main links at the top of my page are styled in a certain way using:

    ------HEADER.PHP:
    <?php 
        $classnamehere= '"linkStyleOne"' ?>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class= <?php echo $classnamehere ; ?>......
```

your code does the following:

- contactus.php is executed.
- header.php is included, setting the $classnamehere to
  '"linkStyleOne"' and creating the actual link with classname
  linkStyleOne.
- After that $classnamehere is set to    linkStyleTwo

This means that you have to assign classname BEFORE including the header.php.

Instead of including it in contactus.php you could do the logic within header.php:

```
<?php
if ($currentPage) == 'contact') { 
    //Set this class when user is on a specific page
    $classnamehere='"linkStyleTwo"';     
}
else {
    $classnamehere= '"linkStyleOne"';
}
?>
```

and just do this in contactus.php

```
<?php 
$currentPage = 'contact';
include 'header.php' 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for puzzling that out for me.  Based on what you've said, I'm trying to figure out a way around it. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: I managed to find a work-around. I removed the $classnamehere variable from header.php and instead declared the variable within contactus.php. It requires a tiny bit more code every time I create a new page, but I suppose I'm okay with that... at least until I find a new method. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @xa - I've edited my answer a bit with an example. That might solve your problem?

Comment: I attempted using an if statement similar to what you have proposed. I used: if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/contactus.php") {$classnamehere='"linkStyleTwo"'} but that simply returns the URL directory of header.php instead of the URL directory of contactus.php...which doesn't work. I guess its just a matter of me doing more research. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @xa - you could use something like basename() - I've updated my answer again. It should be HTTP_REFERER because it's where the user is coming from you want to adress.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER does not seem to return any value. Although I do feel I am making some progress. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] return anything?

Comment: I've tried several different arrangements of it and nothing returns a value.

Comment: @xa- sorry - I think I was think incorrectly. You should check the current file so you could set the classname for the specific page. Check update again!

Comment: basename(__FILE__); inside header.php returns header.php...even when called from contactus.php

Comment: @xa - You could of course tell what page is current , like assigning $currentPage = 'contactus' and then check what value $currentPage has.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 class= <?php echo '"$classnamehere"' ; ?>.
```

to

```
class= "<?php echo $classnamehere ; ?>"
```

Comment: Or shorter `class= "<?=$classnamehere; ?>"`

Comment: I'm using single then double quotes because all my other style tags in HTML use double quotes. This way, this variable name will also be surrounded by double quotes when outputted. In any case, this does not fix my issue.

Comment: @xa. you can't surround a variable in single quotes, variables within single quotes will not be interpolated.

Comment: I fixed up my codes to show more accurately what I have done.

Comment: you could concatenate the quotes to the variable using the . operator to make a new variable as a string and the just echo this.

Comment: @JordiKroon - you should always use <?php echo instead of shorter <?=

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Since PHP 5.4.0 shorthand tags is always available. (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). You are safe when you use >= 5.4.0

Comment: @JordiKroon - available is not the same thing as best practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or use it this way

```
<?php echo '"', $classnamehere ,'"' ; ?>
```

Or this way(im not sure this works)

```
<?php echo '"{$classnamehere}"' ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a PHP class and include it in your header, or make it your header. Invoke it on the page then assign the value for the class variable which you can then echo a separate class function which uses the variable values you require. I can provide an example if you're unfamiliar with the process.

**Header.php simple example:**

```
<?php

class Template
{
    private $active_nav;

    private __construct()
    {

    }

    public function set_active($page = '') // set page test value
    {
        $this->active_nav = $page;
    }

    public function get_active() // return page test value
    {
        return $this->active_nav;
    }

    public function nav_links() // this could be changed to return an entire header or part or whatever -- change the scope accordingly
    {
        // active link CSS is linSktyleOne
        $current_page = $this->get_active();
        $nav_links  = '<ul>';
        $nav_links .=   '<li><a href="index.php" class="' . ($current_page == 'index' ? "linkSytleOne" : "linkStyleTwo") . '">Index</a></li>';
        $nav_links .=   '<li><a href="contact.php" class="' . ($current_page == 'contact' ? "linkSytleOne" : "linkStyleTwo") . '">Contact</a></li>';
        $nav_links .= '</ul>';

        return $nav_links;
    }
}
```

**contact.php simple example:**

```
<?php

require_once('includes/header.php');

$template = new Template;
$template->set_active('contact');

// put all your html or other code here

echo $template->nav_links();
?> <!-- blah blah code finished --> <?
// you can always echo a footer out here through a function in the template as well
```

**index.php simple example:**

```
<?php

require_once('includes/header.php');

$template = new Template;
$template->set_active('index');

// put all your html or other code here

echo $template->nav_links();
?> <!-- blah blah code finished --> <?
// you can always echo a footer out here through a function in the template as well
```

Does all that help make more sense? You only add 1 line of code to each page, and if you really wanted to get fancy you could remove the set function invocation on each page by using a substring of the`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value for a conditional test and put the condition to set the value in the constructor of the class.

Comment: Hmm an example would be nice. I didn't understand you're answer very well.

Comment: OK, I'm going to edit my answer and this will take just a moment... big set of code I'll try to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

If you include code, all variables within included code are global and therefore all chnages are reflected in all parts.
in **header.php**

```
$a = 10;
```

in **contactus.php**

```
include "header.php"
$a = 0;
```

And there is no way of changing `$a` only inside contactus. All code after `$a` change will be using the new value.
You can create temporary variable `$a_copy` inside contactus and then change this variable:

```
$a_copy = $a;
....class= <?php echo '"$a_copy"'...
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I use the new value BEFORE the old value is outputted? Because that is what is happening. the old value is being outputted before the new value is computed.

Comment: I dont think, there is a way. Code is "serial", so everything before change uses the old value and after that the new one. For this kind of behavior I recomend you to use JavaScript and refresh part of site.